# What is this serrated-leaved plant?

Tags: identification

I suspect this is a weed. Am I right? Zone 7a, continental Europe.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is your second plant identification post in the last hour. It might behoove you to download a plant identification app for your phone.

Comment: @Rob Right. however I believe humans are still much better at IDing. btw, I could post dozens of such questions, my garden is rich in species, and even changes significantly each year wrt species ~ by itself.

Comment: Please edit this post and add a photo of the flowers; looks like you'll be getting a bloom by Sunday at the latest.

Comment: For me it a daisy (the large one):Leucanthemum, and yes it is a weed. But for a better identification we need flowers.